# android kotlin : locale des not change after back press

Tags: android, kotlin, locale, android-preferences

I am going to build the android app supporting multi languages.
I have got res-values string , both zh and en directory.

I use Localehelper to change the language for all activities within my application.

When I change my language at Activity B starting from Activity A , the persistent data changes. Then, I press back button on android devices and find out Activity A  does not change its locale.

Would you please tell me how to change the locale under this situation ?

Activity B:

```
  val selectCode =  mySetCode[index]
            LocaleHelper.setLocale( this , selectCode)
            finish()
```

Activity A :

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        initView()

        val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val language = preferences.getString("Locale.Helper.Selected.Language" , null)
        if(language != null){
            LocaleHelper.onAttach( this , language)
        }

    }
```

LocaleHelper.java

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

Comment: you must restart application .. you can look for the same feature implemented other apps like instagram etc

Comment: given I have custom Application.kt to operate, how can I call restarting the application ?

Answer (score 1):

This is [implemented fairly well](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/develop/WordPress/src/main/java/org/wordpress/android/ui/prefs/AppSettingsFragment.java#L363) in the WordPress app.

The key classes/methods are [AppSettingsFragment.changeLanguage](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/develop/WordPress/src/main/java/org/wordpress/android/ui/prefs/AppSettingsFragment.java#L363), [LocaleManager.updateResources](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/develop/WordPress/src/main/java/org/wordpress/android/util/LocaleManager.java#L101), [WPMainActivity.appLanguageChanged](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/7a27168fa577d06992f0223af40dfc54b92ffafc/WordPress/src/main/java/org/wordpress/android/ui/main/WPMainActivity.java#L786), and [ApplicationLifecycleMonitor.onConfigurationChanged](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/develop/WordPress/src/main/java/org/wordpress/android/WordPress.java#L750).

It looks like the new language preference is saved locally then the app is recreated, applying the new language when it's re-instanced. Hope this is enough to run with. I would have just commented but I lack 4 rep :p